declared package "inet.node.tsn" doesn't match expected package
I try to build TSN model using inet.node.tsn package, but there is constant error.
I tried another packages like inet.examples.ieee8021as, but there is the same result.
I also checked another threads with similar problem, but it doesn't help me

Does this help?
